How do I pass pipeline variable into a template and then use in a condition
I want to pass a variable called publish defined in the pipeline definition UI into a template called echo.yml from the main pipeline.yml then in the template use the value of the variable as a condition on a task running or not.
So far no success.
Is this actually possible ?
Simplified example below, the real use case is to control whether or not a publish task executes.
echo.yml:
parameters:
- name: 'desc'
  type: string
  default: none
- name: 'publish'
  type: string
  default: 'false'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  condition: ${{ parameters.publish  }}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo desc is ${{ parameters.desc }}
      echo publish is ${{ parameters.publish }}



pipeline.yml:
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your commands here
      echo SBN IS $(Build.SourceBranchName)
      echo SB IS $(Build.SourceBranch)

- template: echo.yml
  parameters:
    desc: 'my description'
    publish: ${{ variables.publish }}



To use the variable as parameter, you need to directly define variable in Yaml while not UI. Please refer to the answer below for the details. Let me know if you have any queries.

Given that you want to run a task or not based on a parameter, you can use a template expression ${{ if ... }} instead of using a condition.
Example:
# echo.yml

parameters:
  - name: desc
    type: string
    default: none
    
  - name: publish
    type: boolean   # <---------- change to boolean
    default: false

steps:
- ${{ if parameters.publish }}:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo desc is ${{ parameters.desc }}
        echo publish is ${{ parameters.publish }}

# other tasks here

But in case you prefer to use a condition:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo desc is ${{ parameters.desc }}
      echo publish is ${{ parameters.publish }}
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.publish }}', 'true'))

Note:

parameter publish can be changed to boolean, which will be displayed as a checkbox when queuing a new build.


If you define the variable in pipeline definition UI, it cannot get the value as parameter ${{ variables.publish }} for template.
Instead, you can define the variable in main yaml directly，it works then.
trigger: none

variables:
- name: publish
  value: false           # define variable in main yaml

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your commands here
      echo SBN IS $(Build.SourceBranchName)
      echo SB IS $(Build.SourceBranch)

- template: echo.yml
  parameters:
    desc: 'my description'
    publish: ${{ variables.publish }}


